# vs2015 keeps removing hintpath from csproj

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, visual-studio-2015, csproj

In order to get my unit test project to build in Jenkins, I had to add a reference to:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\lib\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System" />
```

However, vs2015.2 locally keeps removing the hint path. In fact, if I undo it, it immediately comes back. How can I prevent v2015.2 from removing the hint path from the CSPROJ? Or, is there a workaround / better way?

Comment: Hmya, this has finger prints of the kind of misery you get into when you violate the license.  Penny wise but many pounds foolish, really rather best to re-image that server.  If you don't then this is going to byte for a long time if you can't remember everything you did.  The quick fix you should not use is to remove the assembly from the GAC again.  Deploy VS to the machine so you can use the proper reference, it belongs in the Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies directory.

Comment: Hmm the reference works fine on Jenkins. The csproj issue is on my desktop at work. I'm using my MSDN license